# exception: no action detected in task

Tags: networking, network-programming, ansible

I'm trying to use the module `junos_get_facts` in Ansible. I've got a main playbook and some tasks within the role called `juniper.junos`. The problem I'm getting is the following exception:

**ansible-playbook main_pb.yml**

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/Users/macuared/Ansible_projects/roles/juniper.junos/tasks/main.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Test junos_get_facts module
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/Users/macuared/Ansible_projects/roles/juniper.junos/tasks/main.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Test junos_get_facts module
  ^ here

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>
exception: no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/Users/macuared/Ansible_projects/roles/juniper.junos/tasks/main.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Test junos_get_facts module
  ^ here
```

**~/Ansible_projects/main_pb.yml**

```
---
- name: Gathering Info from devices
  hosts: man3-rc-test4200-01
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - { role: 'juniper.junos', when: DEVICE_TYPE == 'info'     }
```

**~/Ansible_projects/roles/Juniper.junos/tasks/main.yaml**

```
---
- name: Test junos_get_facts module
  tasks:
    - name: "TEST 1 - Gather Facts"
      junos_get_facts:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname}}"
        user: "YYYYYYY"
        passwd: "XXXXXXX"
      ignore_errors: True
      register: junos

  #  - debug: var=junos

    - name: Check TEST 1
      assert:
        that:
          - junos.facts.hostname
          - junos.facts.serialnumber
          - junos.facts.model
          - junos.facts.fqdn
```

I'm not too sure what's the problem here. I'm using a virtualenv where I've got all my dependencies installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks file in a role should contain a list of tasks.

On the other hand, your file contains a single-element list with a dictionary containing `name` and `tasks` keys. Ansible thus doesn't find any action defined (`name` declaration is correct, but `tasks` is not an action module).

So your `main.yaml` should look like:

```
---
- name: "TEST 1 - Gather Facts"
  junos_get_facts:
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname}}" 
    user: "YYYYYYY"
    passwd: "XXXXXXX"
  ignore_errors: True
  register: junos

- name: Check TEST 1
  assert:
    that:
      - junos.facts.hostname
      - junos.facts.serialnumber
      - junos.facts.model
      - junos.facts.fqdn
```

---

In a playbook tasks are defined under `tasks`, but in roles, the directory structure already determines that.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit clearer now. The problem was with the "tasks" dictionary as you said. It makes more sense now when reading the error message as it was only expecting a list of tasks, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Ansible has [junos_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/junos_facts_module.html), but [junos_get_facts](http://junos-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.1/junos_get_facts.html) is a custom module that needs to be installed separately.